# How to send token to my backend server node.js?

Tags: node.js

I don't know how to send the token to my backend server node.js
I want to send the id token to node.js server and verify Id token in node.js.

This is my android code and node.js code
So I want to send the token from android to node.js and verify ID token.
But i don't know how to do.
This is my node.js code to verify token. This code use for middleware. 
This code used middleware code and verify token 
Help me..``
private void loginUser(String email, String pwd) {

```
firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, pwd)
    .addOnCompleteListener(MainActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
public void onComplete(@NonNull Task < AuthResult > task) {

    //login
    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Login Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        FirebaseUser mUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

        mUser.getIdToken(true)
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<GetTokenResult>() {
                                @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task < GetTokenResult > task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                String idToken = task.getResult().getToken();
                //How to send the token to server
                Log.d(TAG, "idToken  send:" + idToken);

            } else {

            }
        }
    });

    firebaseAuth.addAuthStateListener(firebaseAuthListener);

}else {
    //Login failed

    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "email or password incorrect", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); }} });}
```

function firebaseAuth(req, res, next) {
    let token = req.body.token;

```
authCheck(token)
    .then(decodedToken => {
        let uid=decodedToken.uid;
        console.log(uid);
        return user_infoRepository.uidFindOrCreate(decodedToken.uid)
    })
    .then(user => {

        req.user = user[0]
        next();
    })
    .catch(e => {
        res.json(e)
    })
```

}

var admin = require("firebase-admin");

function authCheck(token) {
 return 
admin.auth().verifyIdToken(token)
};

exports.authCheck = authCheck;

Comment: It would be nice if you can post node.js code

Comment: Thank you for help. I post the node.js code for verify Token.